# sum up the output of 'pkpgcounter -ccmyk' in groups Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black to calculate ink usage

Tags: awk, sed

For printaccounting I'm using Tea4Cups. In /etc/cups/tea4cups.conf I have a line:

```
echo `pkpgcounter  -ccmyk $TEADATAFILE` |sed 's/C\ \://g'|sed 's/M\ \://g'|sed 's/Y\ \://g'|sed 's/K\ \://g'|sed 's/\%/;/g'|sed 's/\./,/g' >>/var/log/accounting_ink.csv
```

`pkpgcounter  -ccmyk $TEADATAFILE` give output like:

```
C :   4.732829%      M :   4.716022%      Y :   3.545420%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.753109%      M :   4.736302%      Y :   3.560630%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.760295%      M :   4.743488%      Y :   3.566019%      K :   0.000000%
```

The more pages a file has, the more output the command will give.
sed strips the output from the characters that are not numeric and turn it into the following:

```
3,699918;  3,285596;  2,983343;  4,169371;  1,596966;  1,635378;  1,621895;  1,306214;
```

Now I need to add every value for C; for M; Y and B to get an idea of the toner/ink usage of the print jobs.
So value 1 and 5; value 2 and 6 etc. But maybe a first step is to determine the total number of values?

Comment: Have a feeling `sed` is not necessary. Looks an awk job for me.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input. Also, don't show data X and tell us running sed produces Y when Y is clearly unrelated to X - keep it simple for us and show ONE data set being operated on. Also - FYI for writing future scripts `sed 's/C\ \://g'|sed 's/M\ \://g'|sed 's/Y\ \://g'|sed 's/K\ \://g'` can be written as just `sed 's/[CMYK] ://g'` (google "regular expressions") and `sed 's/\%/;/g'|sed 's/\./,/g'` is just `tr '%.' ';,'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the individual totals using `awk`

```
echo `pkpgcounter  -ccmyk $TEADATAFILE` | 
awk '{c+=$3;m+=$6;y+=$9;k+=$12}{print}END{printf "C : %.5f%% M:%.5f%% Y:%.5f%% K:%.5f%%",c,m,y,k; print ""}'
C :   4.732829%      M :   4.716022%      Y :   3.545420%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.753109%      M :   4.736302%      Y :   3.560630%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.760295%      M :   4.743488%      Y :   3.566019%      K :   0.000000%
C : 14.24623% M:14.19581% Y:10.67207% K:0.00000%
```

Comment: Useful answer if I leaf out the % and the  ` {print} ` in the middle.
so I would still use sed to do that:
    awk '{c+=$3;m+=$6;y+=$9;k+=$12}END{printf "C:%.5f%% M:%.5f%% Y:%.5f%% K:%.5f%%",c,m,y,k; print ""}'|sed 's/\%//g'

Comment: @Jef You don't think simply not printing the `%` might make more sense than printing it and then removing it with a pipe to a different tool? Btw there's nothing special about a `%` in a regexp so no need to escape it and you definitely do not want to escape characters by default as that can activate them as metacharacters (e.g. `+` or `?`) when they'd otherwise be literal.

Comment: How does `printf` formatting work? Same in awk as every other Algol-based language, `%%` is a literal `%`. Change `%.5f%%` to `%.5f`, etc. Google "printf formatting characters percent" or similar. Things would be easier if you just edited your question to show your expected output though and in particular tell us if the order of the colors in the output is important.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You never need sed when you're using awk so the intermediate output from your sed command isn't useful for this, all we need is your original output from `pkpgcounter`.

You don't show your expected output so it's a guess but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
C :   4.732829%      M :   4.716022%      Y :   3.545420%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.753109%      M :   4.736302%      Y :   3.560630%      K :   0.000000%
C :   4.760295%      M :   4.743488%      Y :   3.566019%      K :   0.000000%

$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) {
        val[i]  = $i
        sum[i] += $(i+2)
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) {
        printf "%s%s: %s", (i>1?OFS:""), val[i], sum[i]
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
C: 14.2462 M: 14.1958 Y: 10.6721 K: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk (multichar `RS`), `file` has the output from the `pkpgcounter`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="%"RS"?"}{a[$1]+=$NF}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' file
C 14.2462
K 0
Y 10.6721
M 14.1958
```

You could pipe the output to the awk instead of using the `file` as source.

**Edit:** Single line printing version, as requested:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="%"RS"?"}{a[$1]+=$NF}END{for(i in a)printf "%s: %s ", i, a[i];print ""}' file
C: 14.2462 K: 0 Y: 10.6721 M: 14.1958
```

**Edit 2:** Single line printing with output order picked from the first record:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS="%"RS"?" }                      # set RS
NR<=4 { b[NR]=$1 }                         # store original order to b
{ a[$1]+=$NF }                             # sum
END { for(i=1;i<=4;i++)                    # respect the original order
          printf "%s: %s ", b[i], a[b[i]]  # output
      print ""                             # finishing touch
}' file
C: 14.2462 M: 14.1958 Y: 10.6721 K: 0
```

Comment: Instead of `file`  you may use the pipe to make things more obvious

Comment: Also `\n` ties your solution to specific implementations.. I would avoid escape sequences like that.

Comment: @sjsam Would that work? I don't have any non-Linux environments around for testing. I mean, it works in Linux but can't test on anything else.

Comment: Linux is fine. The command works, just a few things: I added a ; at the end:
so a[i]}' will become a[i],";"}'
Because the output needs to go to a csv-file. But can you help to put the result of awk in one line, instead of four lines?

Comment: I found
awk -v ORS= ''
will leave out the new lines between the output values, but also at the end....

Comment: If using `ORS` just add one `print "\n"` to the end.

Comment: @James, yes.
` | awk -v ORS='' 'BEGIN{RS="%"RS"?"}{a[$1]+=$NF}END{for(i in a)print a[i],";";print "\n"}`
work fine.
Strange thing happend, it seems the second colon gets swapped with the fourth one. Magenta and Black.
`pkpgcounter  -ccmyk magenta.pdf`

C :   0.000000%      M :  18.496178%      Y :   0.000000%      K :   0.000000%
Results in:
0 ;0 ;0 ;18.4962 ;

Comment: @Jef that's not strange, you're using the `in` operator to decide the order the array elements are visited so the output order is random. See `in` in the awk man page.